# Composer packages changed, even though same version used

Tags: 8, composer

I'm sorry, but in my project, composer update is changing files in my vendor directory even though I'm getting the exact same version of the libraries before & after.  I just want to ask, is this because the packages on packagist are changing, like a branch which is receiving new commits?  Or, is it that something is going wrong in my project?

I thought that if you use composer.lock to keep the versions exactly the same, no files should be changed.

We have kept our libraries versioned, is it possible that a developer modified them incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

`composer update` without any argument tries to update everything.

If you want to use the packages specified in `composer.lock`, run `composer install` instead.

Comment: Just in case this isn’t obvious: `update` also updates composer.lock to reflect the new package versions. So subsequent `install`s from that lock file will also get the new versions

Comment: I'm using a lock file.  None of the versions have changed, and yet many files have been modified, and many of them are removed.

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch What a lock file does is "lock" the dependencies by recording the versions of all the packages at the time the command was executed.    If you want to use the lock file, you need to use `composer install`. If instead you run `composer update` globally, it will change things.  Even if the versions of the modules haven't changed, `composer update` can update symfony components and other "hidden" dependencies and break core without warning. If you run a specific update like `composer update drupal/simplesitemap`, it won't change anything if the module's verison hasn't changed.